# preventDefault() doesn't prevent the action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

When I use `event.preventDefault()` on a link it works, however when I use it on a button doesn't!

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/46sbB/)

My code:

```
<a id="link" href="http://www.google.com">link</a>
<button id="button" onclick="alert('an alert')">button</button>​

$('#link').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
$('#button').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

​
Link action is cancelled, but when I click on the button, still executes the `onClick` action.

Any help? what I want to do is to prevent the button `onClick` action **without changing the button html** (I know how to do

`$('#button').removeAttr('onclick');`

Comment: Don't add events using inline html attributes. Use proper event registration.

Comment: I am not adding anything, the HTML is generated by the Framework, Magento if you want to know..

Comment: Why do you not want to use removeAttr('onClick')?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but I had this problem too, and I decided the cleanest solution for me was to disable the button, and re-enable it when a checkbox was checked. Of course you need to re-disable it again if all the checkboxes are unchecked again.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You want `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` if there are multiple event handlers on an element and you want to prevent the others to execute. `preventDefault()` just blocks the default action (such as submitting a form or navigating to another URL) while `stopImmediatePropagation()` prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree *and* prevents any other event handlers on the same element from being executed.

Here are some useful links explaining the various methods:

- http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/
- http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/
- http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

However, since it still doesn't work it means that the `onclick=""` handler executes before the attached event handler. There's nothing you can do since when your code runs the `onclick` code has already been executed.

The easiest solution is completely removing that handler:

```
$('#button').removeAttr('onclick');
```

Even adding an event listener via plain javascript ([`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)) with `useCapture=true` doesn't help - apparently inline events trigger even before the event starts descending the DOM tree.

If you just do not want to remove the handler because you need it, simply convert it to a properly attached event:

```
var onclickFunc = new Function($('#button').attr('onclick'));
$('#button').click(function(event){
    if(confirm('prevent onclick event?')) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();   
    }
}).click(onclickFunc).removeAttr('onclick');
```

Comment: please read my question!! I said that I know how to do $('#button').removeAttr('onclick'), and litteraly said **without changing the button html**

Comment: It's not possible. Do you just need to preserve the code in there? If yes there's a solution (even though it involves something similar to `eval`: `new Function()`): http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/5wSmG/

Comment: what I want to do: I have a lot of buttons on my page, having different onClick actions, some buttons are dynamically added via Ajax, the buttons are generated by the Framework code, are not mine, I want to execute my code **before** the onClick code of buttons do. (in some cases I may want to prevent the default action from executing)

Comment: Well, you are out of luck. If you cannot get rid of them you need to replace them with properly bound events - you could use $('[onclick]') to get all elements with onclick attributes and use the code from my answer to convert them. Of course you'd have to do this everytime you update something via AJAX.

Comment: @skafandri: That's due to jsfiddle. You have to select "no wrap (body)" - otherwise all your code is inside a function so the function you define is not global. and inline events can only call global functions. http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/46sbB/5/

Answer (score 4):

you need `stopImmediatePropagation` not `preventDefault`.   preventDefault prevents default browser behavior, not method bubbling.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 4):

The `preventDefault` function does not stop event handlers from being triggered, but rather **stops the default action** taking place. For links, it stops the navigation, for buttons, it stops the form from being submitted, etc.

What you are looking for is `stopImmediatePropagation`.

Comment: Ah... You don't really have any control over other event handlers registered on the same element. What you can do is prevent event bubbling. Sorry that I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
$('#button').show(function() {
  var clickEvent = new Function($(this).attr('click')); // store it for future use
  this.onclick = undefined;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/46sbB/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

It have helped me

```
function goToAccessoriesPage(targert) {
       targert.onclick.arguments[0].preventDefault();
       ...
}
```