# Prevent postback in update panel depending on JS confirm box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I got an update panel which contains a gridview and inside each row images (delete icons) to delete that row. I'm trying to condition that given an answer on a regular JavaScript confirm pop up.

```
$(function(){
    $("img.delete").on("click", function(evt){ 
        return false; //Does not work
        /*or*/
        evt.preventDefault();//Does not work either
    });
});
```

Html rendered:

```
    <td>
        <img id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderDefault_Content_Content_Content_Content_DashboardGrid_ctl02_DeleteControl140" class="delete" onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$Content$Content$Content$Content$DashboardGrid','Delete$0')" width="20" height="20" title="Remove item from your list." src="/images/delete_item.png" alt="Remove item from your list." style="border-width:0px;">
</td>
```

It doesn't work because a postback is always performed by the update panel which has its UpdateMode to its default in the sense that I'm not setting it in the markup.

Comment: Place an alert inside the click event and check if the client  event is firing in the first place..

Comment: Yes, I had tried that just to see if I was in the right event (tag for that matter) and it works, with things as simple as alerts. It just does not work when trying to stop the postback from happening.

Comment: Preventing an inline `onclick="..."` event to fire is pretty hard. You need to convert it to an event listener - see my answer over there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10432386/298479

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided by [ThiefMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298479/thiefmaster) worked for me, at: [preventDefault() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432365/preventdefault-doesnt-work/10432386#10432386) with a minor tweak for my case:

```
function pageLoad() 
{
  var inlineFunction = new Function($('img.delete').attr('onclick'));
  $('img.delete').click(function(event){
    if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();         
    }
  }).click(inlineFunction).removeAttr('onclick');
}
```

The pageLoad event is available when using updatepanel+scriptmanager which lets me re-attach the event handlers on every partial postback.

Answer (score 0):

In that case try declaring the `OnClientClick="return Delete()"` in your MarkUp and check if the page is still posting back..

```
function Delete(){

   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like having the `onclick="__doPostBack('controlId','Delete$0')"` as an image attribute results in the page posting back regardless of what you return from `$("img.delete").click()` event.

Can you try calling the `__doPostBack` method from the click event? This worked for me - I was able to control the postback this way.

Going forward, you might have to use `Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference` and expose your postbacks in JavaScript so you can call them from the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I was working my scenario was that the postback was totally blocked. And the case was that I was placing the postback control in div tag and was applying such click event to that div tag with .live event. and that was blocking the postback. So place the image control in div element and do the same for that div. But I am not sure how to allow the postback then.